# Moto G2 doesn't boot, fails to load recovery

Tags: unbricking, motorola-moto-g2

Everything was fine till yesterday but suddenly my moto g2 got stuck and when i tried to go to recovery mode it didnt get started and a message was displayed "failed to load recovery image" and normal boot and factory reset is also not working.Please help me.

Comment: Anything special you did yesterday (i.e. before it "got stuck"), which might give us a clue what might have caused the situation?

Comment: yes day before yday i tried to installed clash of clan .but i was not able to installed it.

Comment: Did it show any errors when you tried? Or were any other errors shown then (e.g. shortly thereafter)?

Comment: after i downloaded that game a message popped up "unfortunately clash of clans could not be installed on your phone.download again".

Comment: Doesn't give me a clou, sorry – a failed app-install shouldn't really cause such a situation (especially concerning recovery mode). Where did you download it from?